# render props vs passing functional component, which one is perfered?

Tags: reactjs

Below is a usage from [React offical document](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html) about the render prop:

```
<DataProvider render={data => <h1>Hello {data.target}</h1>} />
```

And below is its implementation:

```
render() {
  return <div>{this.props.render(this.state)}</div> ;
}
```

While I was practicing this feature, I suddenly realized that this technique is not that fancy, because we can already pass a functional component as a prop to achieve the same thing, for example:

```
render() {
  const { render: Render } = this.props
  return <div>{<Render {...this.state}>}</div> ;
}
```

more readable one:

```
render() {
  const { RenderComponent } = this.props
  return <div>{<RenderComponent {...this.state}>}</div> ;
}
```

In my opinion, `<RenderComponent {...this.state}>` looks much more friendly than `this.props.render(this.state)` since the former is using JSX syntax which every junior React developer have already known how it works, while the latter is confusing (there is already another `render()` member method in the Component).

I want to use the functional component version in my project, but I concern whether there would be any problem behind.

### Question

Which practice is better than the other? (including props and cons)

Comment: "render props vs passing functional component", is this not the same thing? You could also go the `component={}` way a la react router

Comment: [React Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) have been introduced recently and one of their primary goals is to replace render props and higher-order components. Have a look, it's worth it.

Answer (score 0):

The thing here is that In the case of passing an item renderer your component needs to handle the rendering.With render props you can make any component handle child rendering and add any kind of rendering logic without doing any change to the component.From an architectural point of view this is more in align with SOLID principles.